# Wildcard query Elasticsearch doesn't work with multi-words values

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search, wildcard, keyword, elasticsearch-query

I'm facing some problems in the [wildcard query search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html).

My purpose is that if I search for `word1 word2 word3`, I'll find all the results that can have **prefixes and suffixes before and after each word that compose the entire string**.

The structure of my index is:

```json
{
  "my_index": {
    "aliases": {},
    "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "attributes": {
          "properties": {
            "name": {
              "properties": {
                "value": {
                  "type": "text",
                  "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                      "type": "keyword",
                      "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            },
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "settings": {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

So I have a field `attributes.name`(text) where I want to match values.

My index contains objects where `attributes.name` values are:

- `word1`,
- `word1suffix`,
- `word1 word2`,
- `word1 word2suffix`
- `word1 word2 word3`.

Before running the search, I internally **add wildcards before and after each word**:

`word1 word2 word3` => `*word1* *word2* *word3*`

Then I run this query:

```json
{
  "size": 10,
  "index": "my_index",
  "body": {
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "should": [
          {
            "wildcard": {
              "attributes.name.value": {
                "value": "*word1* *word2* *word3*",
                "rewrite": "constant_score"
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "must": [],
        "minimum_should_match": 1
      }
    }
  },
  "explain": false
}
```

The strange thing I'm facing is that, even if in the index I have exactly an object called `word1 word2 word3`, **I cannot find it through this kind of wildcard search** (I know that in that case, it's better a *match_phrase* or *term* query, but it's just to understand why this simple case is not working).

If I try with less words like:

- `*word1*`, I find both `word1`, `word1suffix`, `word1 word2` and `word1 word2suffix`
- `*word1* *word2*`, I find both `word1 word2` and `word1 word2suffix`
- `*word1* *word2* *word3*`, **none**

**So it seems that this strange behavior starts when I search for results with too many words.**

Just for debug, my values are stored in the index in this way:

```json
{
    "attributes": {
        "name": [{
            "value": "word1 word2 word3"
        }],
    }
}
```

**Last consideration:** I managed to find that `word1 word2 word3` by searching in the field `attributes.name.value.keyword` (I think `.keyword` is automatically generated in the index on every textual fields) rather than `attributes.name.value`. The problem is that if I use `.keyword` the analyzer doesn't work, so I think it's not a good solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A wildcard query work based on the pattern, so it will consider entire query as one pattern and due to that may be it is not matching when you add multiple words.

You have two options:

First is using `query_string` type of query as shown below, you can set the value of `default_operator` to `AND` or `OR` based on requirements. This will create `bool` query internally only:

```json
{
 "query": {
   "bool": {
     "should": [
       {
        "query_string": {
          "default_field": "value",
          "query": "*word1* *word2* *word3*",
          "default_operator": "AND"
        }
       }
     ]
   }
 }
}
```

Second, you can have multiple `wildcard` query inside `must` for `AND` query and inside `should` for `OR` query  terms:

```json
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "value": {
              "value": "*word1*"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "value": {
              "value": "*word2*"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "value": {
              "value": "*word3*"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Update**

> I managed to find that `word1 word2 word3` by searching in the field
> `attributes.name.value.keyword` (I think `.keyword` is automatically
> generated in the index on every textual fields) rather than
> `attributes.name.value`. The problem is that if I use `.keyword` the
> analyzer doesn't work, so I think it's not a good solution.

Yes, If you not configured `mapping` then elastic will auto create mapping for each field and if the field is found as `text` type, then it create an inner field with `keyword` type as well.

It is working because `keyword` field does not apply any analyzer and it looks for exact match. If you try `wildcard` query for `attributes.name.value.keyword` field with multiple terms then it will work, but it is case sensitive. So if you have field value like `word1 word2 word3` then `*word1* *word2* *word3*` this query will work, but `*Word1* *word2* *word3*` this query will not work. (See `W` is capital).

**Why it is not working on `text` type field ?**

Because `wildcard` query is the term level query and it don't apply any `analyzer` at query time. It will consider your entire query as one pattern. You are matching query on `text` type field which used `standard` analyzer at indexing time and token your text to multiple terms and index hence it is working for one term and not multiple term.

**Performance Impact**

It is not recommended to use wildcard which is starting with `*` or `?`  As it impact search performance. Below is what mentioned in a document as a warning:

> Avoid beginning patterns with * or ?. This can increase the iterations
> needed to find matching terms and slow search performance.

Comment: I tried the *query_string* and it works. Thanks a lot! Just a clarification for curiosity. In your opinion why does the search with 1/2 words work, but >= 3 not? The pattern seems correct anyway.

Comment: @PaoloMagnani it is not working because `wildcard` is term level query and it dont apply any `analyzer` at query time. it will consider your entire query as one pattern. You are matching query on `text` type field which used `standard` analyzer at indexing time and token your text to multipul terms hence it is working for one term and not multipul term. i am still not sure why it is working for 2 terms because it should not work and i have validated same on my elastic and able to get result for only one term and not multipul terms.

Comment: @PaoloMagnani Please see updated answer for more details.